# Embedding a YouTube player without a video

Tags: youtube

You know how at the end of playing a movie the YouTube player shows you suggestions and a search box? Well, I'd like to embed a YouTube player in *that* state. No video- just a search box and suggestions. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know about official ways, but you could just upload a 1 sec video to youtube, and set the video to that. :-)

Comment: @Chance Yes I considered that. Would rather use a non-hacky way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can set whatever video you want, and then use [Splicd](http://www.splicd.com/) to trim the video to about one second or less, then simply set autoplay to yes, and you have a window with suggestions. This may be to hacky as my previous suggestion was though.

Answer (score 0):

You could cue the video to autostart at the end, meaning it'll play for about a second before showing the suggestions. To avoid showing that 1 second of video, you could mute and hide the video until its finished. Something like this:

```
    window.onload=function(){
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
        var atts = { id: "myytplayer", bgcolor: "#000" };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/e/KmDYXaaT9sA?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&showinfo=0&start=99999&autoplay=1",
                       "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);

    }

  var first = true;

  function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {

      ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
      ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
      ytplayer.mute();
      ytplayer.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {

    ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");

    if (newState==0 && first) {          
        first=false;
        ytplayer.style.visibility = "visible";
        ytplayer.unMute();        
    }

}
```

example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/niklasvh/thpZM/show/